# Jenkins fail to read TEST-TestSuite.xml with errors : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7,674.043"

Tags: jenkins, junit

I use Jenkin execute selenium scripts, the scripts are executed sucessfully, but pop up below error after execute script completely. Any advices?

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7,960.393 sec - in TestSuite

[JENKINS] Recording test results

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to read D:\target\surefire-reports\TEST-TestSuite.xml
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:306)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parsePossiblyEmpty(TestResult.java:244)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:213)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:634)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:615)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy.onEvent(Maven3Builder.java:308)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.onEvent(EventSpyDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(EventSpyExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7,674.043"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.<init>(SuiteResult.java:170)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parseSuite(SuiteResult.java:144)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parse(SuiteResult.java:129)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:301)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: I really suspect it failed due to the comma in the time field of TEST-TestSuite.xml file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="TestSuite" time="7,674.043" tests="2" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
  <properties>
    <property name="PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE" value="x86"/>
    <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io"/>
    <property name="RATIONAL_ICU4J_VERSION" value="4_8"/>

Comment: Yes, you are right. You are getting exception while reading TEST-TestSuite.xml file. And the time property is not in well format.